# How do I stop using my 002R with PT10?

Tags: gear, mac, signal

I'm running 10 on a mac quadcore spdif in/out and going into a UA 2192 ad/da. I rarely/never record more than 2 tracks at a time and figured getting rid of the 002R is just one less outdated component. I don't use the 002r for anything other than out of computer to 2192 ad/da back to 002r.

I have neve, great river, ua, api, etc pres that i just patch into the 2192. One day I will get more than 2 channels of high end AD/DA but in the interim how do set this up to remove the 002r out of the path and just use the 2192 as the interface?

Any help suggestions would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the Mac Pro's digital out is ADAT compliant, but first try Optical out of your tower to the ADAT optical in on your 2192. If that doesn't work, you should be able to go Optical out from your tower to an optical/coaxial converter [(like this one)](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=104&cp_id=10423&cs_id=1042302&p_id=2948&seq=1&format=1#largeimage) in to the coaxial spdif of the 2192. Then go to Setup > Playback Engine. Based on what you're describing you should have the 002 Rack currently active. If you choose "Built-In Digital Output" from the drop-down PT will now use your built in digital output as your playback engine. The 002r should go offline and you can remove it completely from your computer and audio signal chain.

Comment: Thanks Steve I'll give it a shot. I generally track in another room and use this room for overdubs, editing and mixing.

Comment: FYI...the optical outputs on most computers are optical S/PDIF (2 channels only), just like you were thinking.